Transmission with no HDRI in EEVEE
Turning on alpha blend, SSR, and refraction only works if the scene has a HDRI. (If anyone else was struggling, this is the solution.) But I don't want HDRI lighting in my scene. Turning the environment texture strength to zero just makes the material black and opaque again. Is there any other way to get a transmission effect without using a HDRI? Or to have the HDRI only affect transmission?

did you try alpha hashed?
